# gpflow: Is it possible to use data that doesn't fit in memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpflow

I'm trying to train a gpflow model with a huge amount of data that doesn't fit in memory.

I was thinking of using SVGP with minibatch option, but it seems to require a numpy array of the full data, and I don't want to load everything all at once.

Is it possible to do training with data that doesn't fit in memory using gpflow?
Is there an example that does this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `tf.data.Dataset` iterators instead of numpy data. Here is an example:

```
buffer_size = 10000
batch_size = 128

# x_shape is a feature shape, e.g. for CIFAR it will be [32, 32, 3]
xy_shapes = ([], [])
xy_dtypes = (tf.float32, tf.float32)

# Read data from disk
def read_data():
    # Do something, read from disk or anything else...
    yield x, y

# Make dataset, do batching and shuffling
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(read_data, xy_dtypes, xy_shapes)
ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size)
ds = ds.repeat()
ds = ds.shuffle()
ds = ds.batch(batch_size)

# Get data iterators
x_iter, y_iter = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

Now you can create a model with TensorFlow iterators. The only difference from standard approach is that you have to pass `num_data` argument to compute scaling factor correctly.

```
kernel = ...
likelihood = ...
feature = ...

num_data = ... # size of your dataset
model = gpflow.models.SVGP(x_iter, y_iter, kernel, likelihood, feature, num_data=num_data)
```

More information on how to work with tf.data you can find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and sample code!  I didn't realize you could use external minibatches, instead of using the minibatch_size option. I'll put the check mark on this answer after I actually get it to work.